# Why operator () is called twice in my program?

Tags: c++, std

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <stdio.h>

int hcount=0;

struct A{
    int i=0;

    A(){}
    A(const A&a) :i(a.i){}

    A(int const & i):i(i) {        
        printf("A ctor i=%d\n", i);
    }

    A&operator=(A &&a){
        this->i= a.i;
        return (*this);
    }
    bool operator==(A const &rhs) const {
        printf("A optor== i=%d\n", this->i);
        return rhs.i == this->i;
    }
};

namespace std{
    template<>
    struct hash<A> { 
        hash() {            
            hcount=0;
        }
        hash(int t) {
            hcount=t;
        }
        std::size_t operator()(A const &a) const {
            ++hcount;
            printf("hash: hcount=%d a.i=%d\n", hcount, a.i);
            return a.i;
        };
    };
}

int  main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::initializer_list< A > test={
        {A(1)},
        {A(2)}    
    };

    std::unordered_multiset<A> u(4, std::hash<A>(5) );
    printf("1 ---------test.size is %d hcount is %d\n", test.size(), hcount);
            
    u.insert(test.begin(), test.end() );
    printf("2------------test.size is %d hcount is %d\n", test.size(), hcount);
       
    return 0;
}
```

Running the code, I got:

```
A ctor i=1

A ctor i=2

1 ---------test.size is 2 hcount is 5

hash: hcount=6 a.i=1        //operator() is called once for A(1)

hash: hcount=7 a.i=1        //operator() is called twice for A(1)

hash: hcount=8 a.i=2

hash: hcount=9 a.i=2

2------------test.size is 2 hcount is 9
```

I don't understand why the operator() is called twice during insert().
Should it be called only once?

Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: Very very bad practice: `namespace std{
    template<>`

Comment: @S.M. Specializing templates in `namespace std` is recommended by Scott Meyers. I think it was in Effective Modern C++

Comment: Add messages also for the destructors. You'll see about temp copies.

Comment: How else would you specialize `std::hash`?

Comment: Adding things to the `std` namespace is normally bad, *however* in this case, this is one of the sanctioned extension points of the standard library.

Comment: What compiler and language version are you using? You must be compiling with a version pre-c++17.

Comment: @user975989 Why `std::hash` needs to be specialized? It requires a class with the `operator()` that can be implemented outside the std namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably, you are using libc++. Clang with libc++ exhibits this behavior. Clang with libstdc++ does not.

The [initializer list insert](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/libcxx/include/unordered_set#L1215) calls the [range insert](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/libcxx/include/unordered_set#L1628) which calls [__hashtable::__insert_multi](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/libcxx/include/__hash_table#L2215) which calls [__construct_node](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/libcxx/include/__hash_table#L2521) which [hashes](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/libcxx/include/__hash_table#L2529), after which __insert_multi calls [__node_insert_multi](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/libcxx/include/__hash_table#L2040) which also [hashes](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/libcxx/include/__hash_table#L2042).

I see nothing relevant in the standard that prevents this, so it is probably just "QoI".

Comment: Yes, indeed, Clang with libc++ shows this, but not with libstdc++ (GNUC++). thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

it seems the result depends on each compiler. stdout of vc++ and g++ are below:

```
A ctor i=1
A ctor i=2
1 ---------test.size is 2 hcount is 5
hash: hcount=6 a.i=1
hash: hcount=7 a.i=2
2------------test.size is 2 hcount is 7
```

stdout of clang++ (which is the same with yours) is below:

```
A ctor i=1
A ctor i=2
1 ---------test.size is 2 hcount is 5
hash: hcount=6 a.i=1
hash: hcount=7 a.i=1
hash: hcount=8 a.i=2
hash: hcount=9 a.i=2
2------------test.size is 2 hcount is 9
```

you can test your code at https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_gcc

Comment: But your answer doesn't explain it.

Comment: @ThomasSablik actually, you are right. i think there is one more rehashing in the clang++ case. (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/rehash) but i do not know the inner implementation of clang++. :(